# Can Form of the Dragon be given Infect?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I'm play primarily EDH and like to play jank ideas. One thing I've been thinking about is the card [Form of the Dragon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bForm%20of%20the%20Dragon%5d). Is it possible to give Form of the Dragon the infect mechanic?

Answer (score 9):

**Yes, you can, but it's not trivial.**

While Infect works on objects of any type, you can generally only *grant* Infect to creatures. Therefore, you have to turn Form of the Dragon into a creature first. You can do that through e.g. [Liquimetal Coating](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLiquimetal%20Coating%5d), then animate that artifact through e.g. [Skilled Animator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSkilled%20Animator%5d). Or you can turn it into a creature directly with [Opalescence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOpalescence%5d).

Then you can give the resulting creature Infect through e.g. [Grafted Exoskeleton](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrafted%20Exoskeleton%5d).

Comment: Shorter route to creaturedom: [Opalescence](https://scryfall.com/card/uds/13/opalescence)

Comment: @jwodder That'd stop it from doing damage to things with its ability, though.

Comment: @nick012000 Opalescence does not affect abilities.

Comment: @Douglas Oh, right. I had it confused with one of the other white "everything becomes a creature" cards that do result in losing abilities.

Comment: @nick012000 That would be Humility. The Humility + Opalescence combo is the proverbial textbook example for learning about the timestamp system.

Answer (score 3):

I searched Gatherer for cards with "infect" in their rules text, and "creature" neither in their rules text nor their type. [Results](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+%5Binfect%5D+!%5Bcreature%5D&type=+!%5Bcreature%5D)

There are, at time of writing, only two results. One has reminder text telling us that damage causes loss of life (I guess someone at WotC thought we needed reminding of that fact), but with the qualification that this applies only to non-infect damage.

The other card is [Phyrexian Unlife](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPhyrexian%20Unlife%5d), which has

> You don't lose the game for having 0 or less life.
> As long as you have 0 or less life, all damage is dealt to you as though its source had infect. (Damage is dealt to you in the form of poison counters.)

So if your opponent controls Phryxian Unlife, it could cause Form of the Dragon to deal damage *as if* it has infect, but it wouldn't technically have infect.

So it appears that there are no cards that grant non-creatures infect (there does seem to be a trend to allow abilities only on permanents for which they "make sense"), so you can't give FotD infect unless you make it a creature. One way to do so would be to use [Opalescence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOpalescence%5d), which has

> Each other non-Aura enchantment is a creature in addition to its other types and has base power and base toughness each equal to its converted mana cost.

Thus, this would make FoTD a 7/7 creature. You could then use a card such as [Tainted Strike](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTainted%20Strike%5d), which has

> Target creature gets +1/+0 and gains infect until end of turn.

BTW, although you can't give non-creatures infect, AFAIK there's no rule that says you can't have a non-creature with infect. If you make FotD a creature and then cast Tainted Strike on it, and then it ceases to be a creature, it will still have infect. (With Hackworth's suggestion of using [Grafted Exoskeleton](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrafted%20Exoskeleton%5d), however, if FotD ceased to be a creature, then since Grafted Exoskelton is an equipment, it would fall off next time SBA are checked.)